# Spyder history log only going back one day?

Tags: python, spyder

I lost an unsaved file in Spyder, but usually this should be retrievable from the history.py console since I executed it before losing it. However the log seems to only be going back to the start of current day, whereas I’m pretty sure I remember it having a much longer memory before.

Is there some way to access executed lines going further back? Or at least some reason those have been lost so I know what to not do in the future? Thanks

Comment: Could be in a file called `history.py` within your "home" directory. If you're on Windows, that might be something like: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.spyder`.  One of mine is under `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.spyder-py3` for example.

Comment: Yeah that’s what I thought too but in that file too it seems to cut off arbitrarily and doesn’t go back further than yesterday evening, very weird

Comment: This answer might explain your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67526826/clear-history-pane-in-spyder?noredirect=1&lq=1. Only 1k lines are saved to the history file and that number can no longer be altered.