# Clear history pane in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I don't know how many lines are kept for Spyder history, but:

- commands executed 3 months ago have no chance to be searched back to run them again.
- most of the commands in the history are just calls to python files and it's just as easy to reopen the file to run it.
- this long list has to be loaded when the IDE is launched, increasing load time and memory use.

It seems the history tab cannot be cleared using the interface. [Spyder documentation is silent](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/panes/historylog.html) on that.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751140/spyder-ide-console-history) where the OP wanted to increase the history size. The solution provided was to increase a buffer size:

[image]

Entering here a small number (10) and restarting didn't change anything to the tab content. I'm not sure this setting is related to my problem actually. Is there a known solution to this problem?

Comment: This is a question about a bug or feature of a specific IDE, not about coding and as such not really a StackOverflow question? Have you tried posting on relevant user forums or submitted a support request?

Comment: @Grismar. Thanks for trying to help, but asking about programming tools is [perfectly on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (*Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You said

> It seems the history tab cannot be cleared using the interface. Spyder documentation is silent on that.

As you correctly guessed, the content of the History pane can't be cleared up. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-docs/issues/252) in our docs so we don't forget to mention that.

> I found this question where the OP wanted to increase the history size.

That option doesn't have the effect that you'd expect. It only increases/decreases the amount of lines shown inside the IPython console.

The limit of lines shown in the History pane is fixed at 1000 and it's not possible to change it. We will also mention that in our docs.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanations. Is it possible to delete the file containing the history?

Comment: You can remove it but it'll be recreated the next time Spyder is started. We've been meaning to improve the History pane for a long time by using the history database saved by IPython (which would avoid wasting memory by loading a huge file), but unfortunately we haven't had time to do it.

Comment: I guess it'll be recreated empty, or I'm missing something. Can you provide the file path/name?

Comment: Yes, it's recreated empty. The file path is mentioned in our docs.