# Increase length of Spyder history log in history.py

Tags: spyder

The Spyder IDE logs the commands from the console in `~/.config/spyder-py3/history.py`. However, it only stores about 1000 lines of history. How do I increase this limit?

I followed the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26751667/8225166) and increased the buffer size to 5000. However, it does not increase the length of the history file, (and I think it changes only the console buffer size).

In short, I am looking for the equivalent of `HISTFILESIZE` in `.bashrc`. I do not mind even if the buffer size remains short (say 500, the default size), i.e. I don't care about `HISTSIZE` equivalent of `.bashrc`.

P.S. there is another empty file in the config path: `~/.config/spyder-py3/history_internal.py` . Don't know if that matters.

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67573209/13993139 probably explains the answer. It seems that the maximum length of the history file has been set to a fixed value of 1000 lines and can no longer be set by the user. The buffer data appear to be saved as an `sqlite` file in the same config directory.